# C++ unable to access PEB LDR InLoadOrderModuleList

Tags: c++, winapi

I am new to c++ and windows internals. I am trying to print all three PEB_LDR_DATA module lists(InLoadOrderModuleList, InMemoryOrderModuleList, InInitializationOrderModuleList).

After I understood that [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winternl/ns-winternl-peb_ldr_data) shows only InMemoryOrderModuleList in the PEB_LDR_DATA structure and [this](https://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/win32/ntdll/structs/peb_ldr_data.htm) is a more detailed structure.

I have been able to access InMemoryOrderModuleList and print the module list. Getting the first module in InMemoryOrderModuleList:

```
// ldrData data type is PPEB_LDR_DATA
PLIST_ENTRY inMemoryOrderModuleList = &ldrData->InMemoryOrderModuleList;
PLIST_ENTRY currentitem_InMemoryOrderModuleList = inMemoryOrderModuleList->Flink;
LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY inMemoryOrderModuleListItem = *(PLDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY)currentitem_InMemoryOrderModuleList;
```

But when trying to access :

```
// ldrData data type is PPEB_LDR_DATA
PLIST_ENTRY inLoadOrderModuleList = &ldrData->InLoadOrderModuleList;
```

I get the error:

```
class _PEB_LDR_DATA has no member InLoadOrderModuleList
```

I know it is not the right way but also tried to access the list like this:

```
PLIST_ENTRY inLoadOrderModuleList = (PLIST_ENTRY)(ldrData+ 0x0010);
```

inLoadOrderModuleList Flink and Blink is null.

How should I access the lists?

Comment: you need use correct definition of structures - [`LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY`](https://github.com/processhacker/processhacker/blob/master/phnt/include/ntldr.h#L14) and [`PEB_LDR_DATA`](https://github.com/processhacker/processhacker/blob/master/phnt/include/ntpsapi.h#L63)

Comment: After declaring the typedef structure it worked!

Comment: write your comment as an answer so I can mark it as a solution @RbMm

Comment: You could feel free to write your own answer for others to refer to, and [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been unable to access it because the structure that I am using is Microsoft structure [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winternl/ns-winternl-peb_ldr_data). To use the full structure [this](https://www.nirsoft.net/kernel_struct/vista/PEB_LDR_DATA.html) I needed to typedef the full struct.

```
typedef struct _PEB_LDR_DATA
    {
        ULONG Length;
        BOOLEAN Initialized;
        HANDLE SsHandle;
        LIST_ENTRY InLoadOrderModuleList;
        LIST_ENTRY InMemoryOrderModuleList;
        LIST_ENTRY InInitializationOrderModuleList;
        PVOID EntryInProgress;
        BOOLEAN ShutdownInProgress;
        HANDLE ShutdownThreadId;
    } PEB_LDR_DATA, *PPEB_LDR_DATA;
```